# How to type ặ̀ in vim

Tags: vim

So vim has a great feature [digraphs](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/special-characters-in-vim/) for entering special characters like `á`. But it seems to be limited to just 2 characters (hence the "digraphs"). What I'm wondering though is what the vim way is for entering in [more complicated diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_precomposed_Latin_characters_in_Unicode) such as `ằ`, `ệ`, or this with 3 diacritics: `ặ̀`. So if it were following the same sort of vim pattern, I would assume:

```
Ctrl+k a . ( ' => ặ̀
```

Something like that. Wondering how to accomplish this in the vim way, with simple keyboard techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, different digraphs aren't composable. If you need a certain special character often, it's recommended to define your own digraph for it, because that is the shortest way to enter these. E.g.

```
:digraph a* 7857
```

Of course, if there are many combinations that you use, you'll run out of digraphs (or have to use key combinations that are hard to remember).

#### Generic entry

As an alternative, you can enter any special character via [`:help i_CTRL-V_digit`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-V_digit).

```
<C-v>u1eb1
```

The downside is that you have to remember the hexadecimal codepoint.

#### Fake digraphs

You can also define (insert and command) mode mappings that "feel" like digraphs; these are not limited to two combining characters, and also don't prevent you from using standard digraphs as well:

```
:noremap! <C-k>a.(' ằ
```

This probably is the approach you'd favor. To persist these, put the definitions into your `~/.vimrc`, or a separate `~/.vim/plugin/mydigraphs.vim`.